# DELETE method not supported angularsjs springboot rest

Tags: javascript, rest, spring-boot

i'm using spring boot (backend) and angulars js (frontend) and the communication between the two frond with restful web service .
there is my rest service :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/structure")
public class StructureNotificationRestContolleur {

    @Autowired
    StructureNotificationService StructureNotif;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/deleteStruct/{ch}", method=RequestMethod.DELETE )
    public @ResponseBody void DeleteStructure(@PathVariable (value="ch") String ch) 
    {
         StructureNotif.DeleteStrucuture("#"+ch);
    }
}
```

and there is my function angulars js :

```
$scope.deleteST = function (ids) {
    $http.delete('http://localhost:8080/structure/deleteStruct/' + ids).
    success(function (data) {
        alert(ids);    
    });
}
```

but when clicking in the delete button , i get this error :

DELETE method not supported ????

Comment: yes in my RESTControlleur                                                    RequestMapping(value = "/deleteStruct/{ch}", method=RequestMethod.DELETE )

Comment: What is `ids`? It sounds plural. Can you confirm that it's a string with no spaces and no characters which might be illegal in a URL?

Comment: Might be the issue ... you have put `@ResponseBody` on a `void` method.

Comment: @Steve That's not the issue.

Comment: it's the same ,with @ResponseBody or without it , Steve what is the issue

Comment: Yep ... just tracked out some similar code of my own and tested it. The annotation shouldn't be there, but it's not what is causing the problem. Can you let us know what the value of `ids` is? Or show an example based on a curl command instead of your JavaScript code?

Comment: btw - In my test, I get the error message above if I don't pass an argument, so it seems highly likely that the value of `ids` is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks correct. Maybe you forgot to add the application context to your requestUrl. Try it with a relativ path, like this:

```
$scope.deleteST = function (ids) {
$http.delete('structure/deleteStruct/' + ids).
    success(function (data) {
        alert(ids);    
    });
}
```

Comment: the same think : Request method 'DELETE' not supported

Comment: Are you sure that your url request mapping is correct?

Comment: there is my mapring request                                                    RequestMapping(value = "/deleteStruct/{ch}", method=RequestMethod.DELETE )

Comment: Can you create an other method with  RequestMapping(value = "/deleteStruct2/{ch}", method=RequestMethod.GET) an call them manually in your browser to check that the url is correct?

Comment: when changing the method type from DELETE to GET , i get this error                     Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`dbnotification`.`champ`, CONSTRAINT `fk_Champ_Structure_notification1` FOREIGN KEY (`structidstructurenotification`) REFERENCES `structurenotification` (`idstructurenotification`) ON DELETE N)

Comment: delete the child rows first! :)

Comment: When i change the methode from delete to get in the controlleur rest class, and i passe this url in the bar address http://localhost:8080/structure/deleteStruct2/AE the element with id AE deleted ???????????,,

Comment: It try's to remove the Entity with the id AE, but it can't because some other entities refer to them.

Comment: i change the DELETE methode in the Rest Controlleur class to delete the list of child elements , but its the same think, ????

Comment: public void DeleteStrucuture(String idStructure) {
   
   Structurenotification s=this.GetStructureNotification(idStructure);
   
   for(int i=0;i<s.getChamps().size();i++)
   {
    champservice.DeleteChamp(s.getChamps().get(i).getIdchamp());
   }
   structureRepository.delete(idStructure);
  }